# From PE to ELF. about structures

Tags: elf

I saw [this header with structures](http://users.skynet.be/bk329156/html/file__formats_8hh.html)

I'm asking you to explain me some abbriviation.

Linux: `ELF32_HDR , ELF64_HDR`

What type should be ELF files `ELF32_HDR->e_type`?

For example, Windows has `IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE` and `IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE` to differ PE from other.

First four bytes from `ELF32_HDR->e_ident` contains signature. And what should be in ELF `ELF32_HDR->e_type`?

Windows: `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER->AddressOfEntryPoint`

Linux: `'ELF32_HDR->e_entry`'?

Windows: `'IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER->ImageBase'`

Linux: `'ELF32_HDR->e_ehsize'`?

Windows: `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER->Name; VirtualAddress; SizeOfRawData`

Linux: `ELF32_SHDR->sh_name; sh_addr; sh_size`?

Windows: `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` inits from `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS`

Linux: `ELF32_SHDR` inits from `ELF32_HDR`? May be some argument point to section_headers? `e_shstrndx` ? `e_phoff`?

I think it's `ELF32_HDR->e_phoff`.

Windows: `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT` can tell us about dll modules.

Linux: What can tell us about daemons?

What is `ELF32_SYM , ELF32_DYN m ELF32_REL , ELF32_RELA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely open http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf

And please reform your question, it's not obvious that you're trying to migrate from one file format to another.

It's very clear there. For example, `e_type` explained:

```
Name      Value  Meaning

ET_NONE   0      No file type
ET_REL    1      Relocatable file
ET_EXEC   2      Executable file
ET_DYN    3      Shared object file
ET_CORE   4      Core file
ET_LOPROC 0xff00 Processor-specific
ET_HIPROC 0xffff Processor-specific
```

As for `e_entry`, I believe you're right. The same for `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER->Name; VirtualAddress; SizeOfRawData`